# Duplicate identical object

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, unique

None of the solutions I've found to this question are satisfying to me.

I have a controller that creates, removes and duplicates items. Whenever I duplicate an item they would obviously have the same properties. Yet I want to be able to distinguish and identify them. Also the duplicated item needs to be inserted right after the original item.

There are some really simple solutions I came up with:

1. Generate a unique key and assign it to the created item.
2. Have some id-counter that increments itself by one each item a ID has to be assigned (more or less the same as solution 1; probably faster but unnecessarily pollutes the code).
3. Insert item in array and re-render so it gets a `$$hashKey` from Angular.

I imagine the first solution would be best practice since I can create a module for this. The second solution would probably be the fastest solution but I dislike the fact I need a counter. The third solution seems not to be a good idea at all since this goes against the principles of Angular.

I don't know if it is of any use but here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9e6mk76o/1/).

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>{{item.id}}</p>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="duplicateItem(item)" value="Duplicate"></input>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="removeItem(item)" value="Remove"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            type: 'text',
            id: 'ID_1' },
        {
            type: 'text',
            id: 'ID_2' }
    ];

    $scope.duplicateItem = function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function(item) {
        // Removes item
    };   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). This will perform a deep copy that will be recognized by angular as a different object.

The problem when you just duplicate the whole object in native javascript is that you also copy the internal id on which angular bases its model<->view mapping.

Here is an updated version of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9e6mk76o/2/) where you can see it in action.

Comment: So JavaScript knows which object to delete when they have to identical properties???

Comment: @Pascal actually they don't, since angular has added a distinct internal identifier for each of the copies. Add some logging and you should see a `$$hashKey` property on the items.

Comment: However you're right that my splice would not work as intended if this was plain native javascript.

Comment: @Pascal hmmm actually I checked and the $$hashkey is identic for copied items. There might be another identifying mechanism I'm missing, or maybe angular.copy doesn't work as I intended. Let me check and I'll get back to you

Comment: But that $$hashKey is identical to the original item: http://jsfiddle.net/9e6mk76o/3/

EDIT: Ninja'd

Comment: @Pascal Yeah, I just checked and `$$hashkey` isn't the identifier I was thinking about. However, the angular.copy works as intended : both items are not related after copy and changes to one will no be replicated to the other. Check that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9e6mk76o/4/) if you want : duplicate the first item. If you "change" the copy, the outside `<p>` won't be changed, whether if you change the original it will

Comment: However I have to agree I don't know why my splice works fine. I would expect the first item with corresponding $$hashkey, id and type to be removed rather than the right one. There must be some javascript internal mechanics I'm missing.

Comment: I am interested as well if you figure it out - I certainly thought it was based off the hashkey.

Comment: @IfTrue Okay so this won't work in angular 1.2.1 and later, where identity definitely is based on $$hashkey. However, Pascal is using angular 1.1.1, which must somehow maintain an internal mapping. I won't dive further in this but here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxzayzow/) that you can switch from angular 1.1.1 to 1.2.1 to showcase the different behaviour. Change the dependency, the html containing div and the controller function and notice how 1.2.1 will produce different $$haskeys on copy and refuse a simple copy.

Comment: @Aaron Ah okay so it is as I thought - angular.copy will produce a different hashkey correct (and from your findings apparently this is from 1.2.1 and onwards)? Thanks for the investigation and follow up.

Comment: @IfTrue I'm not sure of the exact version where $$hashkey becomes relevant but yes, in 1.1.1 it doesn't seem to be while in 1.2.1 it is. I'm also pretty sure it still is in recent angular versions. I tested these specific versions because they're the only one available on jsFiddle.